# How Can I Check the checkbox that belongs a GridVIew?

Tags: javascript, gridview

I want to do a javascript function that check the unchecked checkbox. My function nowadays, check all the unchecked checkbox, and I need that just check a specific GridView unchecked checkbox

```
function checar() {    
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].type == "checkbox") {
            el[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to first limit the scope of your search for elements. One way to do so would be to use getElementById

```
function checar() { 
var grd = document.getElementById("<%=grd.ClientID%>"); // <-- Add this line
var el = grd.getElementsByTagName("input"); // <-- change the scope of this to grd
//rest of your code here.
}
```

Sample using divs, but you'll get the idea I think: http://jsfiddle.net/8LRkk/

**Edited** to include setting the specific Grid ID.

Comment: Yes, I saw it before I ask here, and I tried this solution, but the var grd, return null.

Comment: Be sure that you are putting the actual Rendered ID of your GridView, not what is set in the code, example  document.getElementById("<%=grd.ClientID%>");

Comment: Not seeing your entire code, it's hard to say what's going on, but the above _should_ be working as you desire. Something is going on getting the ID of your grid view.

Answer (score 0):

To get at all of the checkboxes of a particular gridview, you need to grab checkboxes whose `ClientID` contain the portion of the gridview's `ClientID` as well since all controls have an id which is "stacked".

Your function should work as a base, it just needs to have an added check in it:

```
function checar() {    
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    // Get the client id of the gridview from ASP here
    var gvID = '<%= this.myGridview.ClientID %>';

    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        // Call the id of the checkbox and check to see if it
        // contains the client id of the gridview at the same time
        if (el[i].type == "checkbox" && el.id.indexOf(gvID) != -1) {
            el[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sample will get all checkbox ? because I need to click in a button "Select All" and then, all will be selected.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: No, when I read your question it sounded like you needed a single checkbox from the gridview checked. I'll adjust my answer to match all checkboxes from a grid.

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: Update posted.